# H lookup in excel

Tags: excel

I have data
1.

```
country      city
US            NY
UK            LON
IND           DEL
BEL           BRU
FRANCE        PAR
```

2.

```
Country   US       UK      IND     BEL     FRANCE
```

How to lookup tab2 to tab1 to get o/p as below

```
Country   US       UK      IND     BEL     FRANCE   
City      NY      LON      DEL      BRU     PAR
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

See the [support document](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Transpose-rotate-data-from-rows-to-columns-or-vice-versa-3419f2e3-beab-4318-aae5-d0f862209744) from Microsoft which says:

> 1. Select the range of data you want to rearrange, including any row or
>      column labels, and press Ctrl+C.
>
> NOTE:  Make sure you copy the data to do this. Using the Cut command
>   or Ctrl+X won’t work.
>
> 2. Right-click the first cell where you want to paste the data, and
>      pick Transpose  Tranpose button image .
>
>    Pick a spot in the worksheet that has enough room to paste your
>      data. The data you copied will overwrite any data that’s already
>      there.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand, but if the tab 1 istarts at A1 then:

```
=VLOOKUP(B8,$A$2:$B$6,2,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple VLOOKUP as per below:

[image]